# java Login throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I'm experimenting with **Java** **Login** method. Can someone explain to me why i get this **NullPointerException** . . .

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Remote implements ActionListener {
    Action  action;
    Gui     gui;
    String  output;
    Boolean result;

public Remote(Gui g, Action a) {
    action = a;
    gui = g;
    actionListenerMeth(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    try {
        String a = gui.username_tf.getText();
        char[] c = gui.password_tf.getPassword();
        String b = new String(c);
        result = action.login(a, b);
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (result == true) { //<--this is where Eclipse shows me the error ...
        output = "You are Successfuly Loged In!";
    } else {
        output = "Username or Password is Wrong!";
    }
    gui.result_lb.setText(output);
}

public void actionListenerMeth(ActionListener ae) {
    gui.login_bt.addActionListener(ae);
}

}
```

Here is the console log:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at nova.Remote.actionPerformed(Remote.java:29)  at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>
> ........etc

And here is my .**login** method in **Action** class:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Action {
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
String dbName = "test";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String username = "root";
String password = "password";
Boolean result;
///
public Boolean login(String x, String y)
{
    String user_var = x;
    String pass_var = y;
    ///
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, username, password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM java where username='"+user_var+"' and password='"+pass_var+"' ");

        while(res.next())
        {
            String user = res.getString("username");
            String pass = res.getString("password");

            if((user_var.equals(user)) && (pass_var.equals(pass))){
                result = true;
            }else{
                result = false;
            }
        }
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (result);
}
```

}

Comment: What does `action.login` do?

Comment: which line is line 29?  Something is null on that line: `nova.Remote.actionPerformed(Remote.java:29)`

Comment: If the exception is thrown in `if (result == true)` that mean `action.login(a, b) == null`

Comment: [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1679537)

Comment: show your `login` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) before you using box type `Boolean`. The error comes box type `Boolean` equals with unbox type boolean value true or false.If you use box type, you code should be

```
Boolean result;    
if (result != null)
```

or if you use unbox type ,your code should be

```
boolean result;
if (result == true) {//TODO}
```

actually ubox boolean no need `==` . You can declare likes this

```
if (result){//DO SOMETHING}
```

Comment: You're right, thanks! Just had to change from **Boolean** to **boolean** and `if(result){//...}` was enough. I'm new and i'm learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `action.login(a, b);` returns `null`.

So in your case the Boolean object `null` should be compared with a primitive `false`.
So `null` will be converted to a primitive `boolean` using `Boolean.booleanValue()`, wich gives a `NullPointerException`.

So you have to change:

```
if (result == true)
```

To

```
if (result != null && result == true)
```

Comment: True, but presumably the OP doesn't think `login` should be returning null.

Comment: The question is `Can someone explain to me why i get this NullPointerException` the the answer is not wrong

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `result` as a `Boolean` object, not a `boolean` primitive.  When `if (result == true)` executes, the VM attempts to convert `result` to a boolean primitive using a method call on `result`, which is null.

Solution:  make `result` a boolean.  This will implicitly be initialised as `false`.

Incidentally, you don't need to say `if (result == true)`, you can just say `if (result)`.

Comment: *"Solution: make result a boolean."* No... this will just cause the exception to throw on a different line.

Comment: There are a few issues with this code, but the specific question asked is related to converting a null object to a primitive.

Comment: It's not a *solution*. The problem is `login` returns `Boolean` which is null.

Comment: Yes it is, because even if `gui.username_tf.getText()` throws an exception, `result` will still be a valid primitive with a value of false (or, since it's an instance variable, whatever it was the last time - it should actually be a local variable).  The, the test `if (result)` will evaluate to false instead of throwing an NPE.

Comment: But also, yes - action.login should return a primitive or a non-null Boolean.  Like I said, this code has other issues.